# text message with yes no option

Tags: android, ios, sms, sms-gateway

I need to send a sms text message to a phone(Android/iOS) in which they can have the option within the sms text message either "Yes" or "NO". Can someone explain to me how to go about to get this done? I tried looking at third party libraries but could not find any

Comment: This is way too broad. What have you tried already? Have you gotten a start at all yet?

Comment: Are you asking if you can gather feedback from a user via SMS (e.g. reply "YES" to agree) ? If so, you can't do that on iOS. I can't speak for Android but due to privacy protection iOS provides no means for an app to be able to read incoming (reply) text messages.